# Change Outlook call application

Tags: windows-10, office365, outlook-addin, phone-call

In Outlook (2016/365), when you select a contact, there's an option to call that contact

[image]

When you select the option to call the person, Outlook seems to ignore the Windows 10 settings for 'tel:' or 'callto:' protocol handlers and present you with a dialer.
Or, when Microsoft Teams is running, it will call the number through Teams.

I'm looking for a way to make the call through my own VOIP app.

Does anyone know if Outlook follows a specific protocol handler or how I can override its default behaviour?

I know it's possible to create a plug-in to add my own dialing options in a separate menu, but I'm looking for a way to override the behaviour of this default menu.

Thanks!

Comment: I would also be interested in a solution. We use an other application for phone calls (OpenScape fusion) and it seems Outlook does not use the default app behind the tel: protocol. This is really annoying. My workaround is to use an autohotkey script to quickly dial-in. but still I need to select the phone number manually.

Answer (score 0):

See [Integrating IM applications with Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/shared/integrating-im-applications-with-office).